# Android Media player gives error E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648) when I try to play mp4 from a firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

When I tried to play video directly from link it works. But When I am trying to play it using firestore, it is showing me "Can't play video."

In logcat I am getting this error.
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)

E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

```
class Show_Video : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_video)

        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(vv_show)

       
        val vid_res = "191221"

        mFireStore.collection(vid_res)
            .document(vid_res)
            .get().addOnSuccessListener {
            document -> document.toString()

                val onlineUri : Uri = Uri.parse(document.toString())

                vv_show.setMediaController(mediaController)
                vv_show.setVideoURI(onlineUri)
                vv_show.requestFocus()
                vv_show.start()

        }


    }
```

Here is my db snapshot.
[db snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7tau.png)

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and show us the field which holds the video URL.

Comment: I have added snapshot.

Comment: What is the value of `vid_res`?

Comment: I changed the value. still same error occurs.